# ASP.NET MVC Passing array/collection of DateTime in ActionLink from View to Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to pass Collection of DateTime from my View:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Hello", "Index", "Home", new { dates = new Collection(){date1, date2)} })
```

Here is my action:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index(int? page, string searchString, ICollection<DateTime> dates)
{ ...
```

But i always get null in dates. Any suggestions?

**Update**

The problem is as i think it creates incorrect url:

```
http://localhost:39152/Home?dates=System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection%601%5BSystem.DateTime%5D
```

Btw i added:

```
public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
{
  var value = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);
  var date = value.ConvertTo(typeof (DateTime), CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
  return date;
}
```

And to action:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index(int? page, string searchString, [ModelBinder(typeof (ModelBinders.DateTimeBinder))]  ICollection<DateTime> dates)
{ ...
```

Comment: implement IModelBinder

Comment: @rt2800 could you please check if i'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I don't know how to do it with UrlActionLink or Url.Action because they will encode the bracket, but the default ModelBinder can handle ICollection dates if you pass the correct query string, something like this

```
    var dates = new[] { new DateTime(2012, 11, 12), new DateTime(2013, 09, 13) };
    <a href="@(Url.Action("Index", "Home"))?@(string.Join("&", dates.Select((date, i) => Url.Encode("dates") + "[" + i + "]=" + date.ToString("s"))))">Hello</a>
```

The url will look like this /Home/Index?dates[0]=2012-11-12T00:00:00&dates[1]=2013-09-13T00:00:00